# When my DocumentTermMatrix is run, the spaces between my data disappears

Tags: r, database, csv, text

[My code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymam0.png)

punctuation and numbers are removed, case normalisation to lower case was done. i have converted my dataset from xls to csv file.

after running DTM on R: adelaidetolondonviasingaporewasmyfirstexperienceofbusinessclassonsingaporeairlinesaandiwasdisappointedfoodifecrewetcwerefinethoughnothingexceptionalbuttheseating

Data on dataset:
Adelaide to London via Singapore was my first experience of Business Class on Singapore Airlines A380, and I was disappointed. Food, IFE, crew etc. were fine (though nothing exceptional) but the seating

Comment: hello @Dave2e i have tried removing that line and it still does not work. I don't think it will make a difference sadly

Comment: The step "#removing non-english words" is removing everithing that is not a letter, even spaces and punctuation. That is the problematic step. Try adding a space inside the regexp: `[^A-Za-z ]`